# How to fix 'node can not be found' in osmdata package

Tags: r, openstreetmap, r-sf

I would like to get some data (where are the highways in given location) from osmdata package. But from time to time I get an error:

Error in rcpp_osmdata_sf(doc) : node can not be found

I have tried to google it, but couldn't find anything helpful. Below you can see the code I used to get the data.

```r
pdms_tmp <- base::data.frame(Long = 21.7478965, Lat =  49.6931262) %>% 
        sf::st_as_sf(crs = 4236, coords = c("Long", "Lat")) %>%
        sf::st_transform(crs = 3034) %>%
        sf::st_buffer(dist = units::as_units(1000, "m")) %>%
        sf::st_transform(crs = 4326) %>%
        sf::st_bbox()

osm_tmp <- (pdms_tmp %>%
              osmdata::opq() %>%
              osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "highway") %>%
              osmdata::osmdata_sf())$osm_line
```

Like I said, from time to time it throws an error. But that error might not happen twice on the same coordinates.

Comment: I have not managed to produce such an error. Since it happens for you only sometimes, it is likely that something else is causing it, e.g. no data being retrieved due to a network glitch or rate-limiting of the used API. It would probably help to assign the results of the different `osmdata` calls to individual variables, enabling you to check these intermediate results.

Comment: The only relation to Rcpp is `osmdata` using it. But it is unlikely that the error has anything to do with that. I am removing the tag.

Comment: You're right Ralf, this is almost certainly because the overpass server that provides `osmdata` sometimes fails silently and returns both `http` success yet no data. You'll then get `node can not be found` because there are no nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on slow/intermittent internet but it worked fine on a steady connection (your code ran without errors too). I think the overpass API has a [default timeout](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Resource_management_options_.28osm-script.29) duration that can be too short.